# setSimpleFullScreen causing app to lose focus in electron?

Tags: electron

I'm trying to add `simpleFullScreen` [support to VS Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/55267/files), and whenever it's toggled on or off, the application completely loses focus, and I need to refocus it before I can type or toggle fullScreen again.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix using github code search.

Calling `currentWindow.webContents.focus()` after `setSimpleFullScreen` does the trick, although I still don't know why it loses focus in the first place. Maybe just an electron bug?

https://github.com/igorgladkoborodov/vv/blob/60b513d4c728fe9a6d723d5b1d1808c2ef9ef634/src/renderer/nvim/features/fullScreen.js#L27